# cloudkit notifications for a specific field within a record

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, nspredicate, cloudkit, cknotification

I have cloudkit notifications working. When someone changes the record, the subscribers are notified. My subscription definition looks like:

```
         NSPredicate *searchConditions = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K = %@", CLOUDKIT_PUBLIC_ID_GUID, theCloudGUID];
         int subscriptionOptions = CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecordUpdate | CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecordDeletion;
         CKSubscription *publicSubscription = [[CKSubscription alloc] initWithRecordType:CLOUDKIT_RECORDNAME_PUBLIC_ID
                                                                               predicate:searchConditions
                                                                                 options:subscriptionOptions];

         CKNotificationInfo *notificationInfo = [CKNotificationInfo new];
         notificationInfo.alertLocalizationKey = CLOUDKIT_NOTIFICATION_PUBLIC;
         notificationInfo.shouldBadge = NO;
         notificationInfo.alertBody = CLOUDKIT_NOTIFICATIONBODY_PUBLIC;
         publicSubscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo;

         [publicDatabase saveSubscription:publicSubscription completionHandler:^(CKSubscription * _Nullable subscription, NSError * _Nullable error)
          {
              //error handling
          }
```

The thing is, there are multiple fields in this record. I only want to alert the subscriber when one specific field changes.

When creating the subscription, is there a way to set the search predicate to detect a change in a specific field? I read through the various Predicate docs, but didn't see this specifically mentioned.

Or, when receiving the notification, is there a way to see which fields changed? In `didReceiveRemoteNotification` I tried:

```
 CKQueryNotification *queryNotification = [CKQueryNotification notificationFromRemoteNotificationDictionary:userInfo];
```

But `queryNotification.recordFields` is null.

As a worst case, I have considered breaking the specific field out into it's own record, but then I have the overhead of maintaining more records tied together by a common GUID. I was hoping to keep this more compact.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is aging a bit, so maybe you already figured this out, but using the `desiredKeys` property may help: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/cknotificationinfo/1514931-desiredkeys

If these notifications are silent pushes, you could look at the payload to see if certain keys changed and have your app react accordingly.

If these are push (visible-to-the-user) notifications, I don't think you can push based on the key changing per se. You could set an `NSPredicate` on your `CKQuerySubscription` if you were testing *how* the value changed (is it equal to *this* or not equal to *that*, etc.), but I'm not sure about it being triggered for any change at all.

Comment: Thanks. I actually don’t remember how I got around that. I know I found an alternative that sufficed but it’s been a good while since I looked at that code.